# What is the best way to broadcast a large data via socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

What would be the best way to broadcast large data (>150MB) via socket.io to all the clients?
The problem I'm facing right now is that I'm hosting my app on Heroku and by using this service there is a 30s timeout for `POST` requests, therefore I'm unable to broadcast large data right now.
Note: my data is a very long string.

At this point, the solutions I was thinking of are:

- compressing the string but this adds an additional waiting time before the broadcast and it can be quite long
- sending the data in chunks => this solution won't make the broadcast faster but it might be a workaround for the 30s timeout issue

Is there a better way to broadcast this data to the clients ?

Comment: Why do you have to wait to finish your POST request until the socket.io upload is done?  Why not just finish the POST request and let the socket.io take whatever time it needs to?

Comment: What is this data?  Is it the same data that all clients are getting?

Comment: @jfriend00 this is not something I can control actually, Heroku has a built-in timeout all I do is emit to the socket.io server but this POST request takes a very long time ( >30s) since the data is very big. Therefore the request is dumped

Comment: @Brad it's a very long string, and yes it's the same data

Comment: @Observablerxjs A long string for what?  Can you give us more context so we can help you in a better way?

Comment: @Brad we are using babylon.js, when a client imports a scene we want to broadcast it to the others so we serialize the scene via the babylonjs serializer and then we stringify the resulted object and we broadcast it

Comment: I don't think you understand my point.  Your sending of data over socket.io has NOTHING to do with when the POST request finishes.  You can finish the POST request and go about your merry way sending data over the socket.io connection all day.  The KEY here is don't want until the socket.io data is done before you complete the POST request.  Instead, complete the POST request right away.

Comment: @Observablerxjs There are some key questions here though... are you sure you want to serialize everything as a string?  Surely there's a more efficient binary format available?  And, what sends/receives?  What is the receiving end expecting?  Why can't you make a normal HTTP GET request, so you can take advantage of proxies, caching, normal web servers, etc.?  You can still stream that way if you want to.

Comment: @Brad I didn't find another way of broadcasting a scene in babyton.js and since the data to generate is not on the server side but in the file system of the client that create the scene. Therefore I can't use a GET request. I was wondering if it's possible to create chunks over socket.io. FYI the string I'm trying to brodcast is 174'682'131 long (character count) I was thinkg if I can create a chunk of let's say 50'000'000 character each this can fix the timeout issue I'm having. Do you think this is a good way of brodcasting a large string ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you "trigger" the client to make a `GET` request to download the data rather than try sending it via socket.io?  Not sure if there's a timeout for `GET` requests or not.

Comment: This is probably the simplest way to go because browsers are already really good at downloading large things over http whereas socket.io is not.

Comment: the data can't be accessed with a `GET` request since it's a resulting string from a serialization (i.e. :"we are using babylon.js, when a client imports a scene we want to broadcast it to the others so we serialize the scene via the babylonjs serializer and then we stringify the resulted object and we broadcast it")

Comment: @Observablerxjs - The data can too be accessed via a GET.  You just have to insert it in a cache on your server (any module-level object that can be reached later) and create a dynamic URL that references that specific cache item.  That is a solvable problem if you want to.